# why actionUp method isn't called?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I want to give the user the possibility to draw something in a View. But I have problems with one single line, because `ACTION_UP` of my overriden `onTouch` Event will never be called. I tried it with a switch case statement and with if else. I heard something about that the `ACTION_DOWN` must return true, in order to invoke the `ACTION_UP`. But this doesn't work for me.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Drawing extends View {

    //drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private Context contextDrawing;

    public Drawing(Context context, View zeichnungsview/*, AttributeSet attrs*/){
        super(context/*, attrs*/);
        contextDrawing = context;
        //View drawingView = (View) findViewById(R.id.zeichnenView);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contextDrawing);
        //View.inflate(contextDrawing, R.layout.openproject, null);
        //Log.d("drawingView", "drawingView " + inflater + "|" + drawingView);
        zeichnungsview.setOnTouchListener(drawingOnTouchListener);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    //setup drawing
    private void setupDrawing(){

        //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contextDrawing.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        //View drawingView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.openproject, null);
        //View drawingView = (View) findViewById(R.id.zeichnenView);
        //drawingView.setOnTouchListener(drawingOnTouchListener);
    }

    final OnTouchListener drawingOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();

            int action = event.getAction();
            int code = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

            Log.d("touchX", "touchX " + touchX + "|" + event.getAction());
            //respond to down, move and up events

            if(code == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Log.d("ACTION_DOWN", "ACTION_DOWN");
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            }
            if (code == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);

                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
            }
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("ACTION_DOWN", "ACTION_DOWN");
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("ACTION_MOVE", "ACTION_MOVE");
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);

                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("ACTION_UP", "ACTION_UP");
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);

                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
            //redraw
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    };
    //size assigned to view
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    //draw the view - will be called after touch event
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    //register user touches as drawing action
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        Log.d("touchX", "touchX " + touchX);
        //respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        //redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    //update color
    public void setColor(String newColor){
        invalidate();
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }
}
```

I still have the problem that nothing works. So I tried it with a simple example. In this only a rectangle shall be drawn when I click onto the view. There is no Action_Up anymore, but I have the problem, that the `onDraw( )` method never gets called. Besides that I don't know how to call the class from an other exactly.

So here is my main Activity (I tried it with `new Drawing(context)` in this case):

final OnClickListener zeichnenViewClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d("zeichnenViewClickListener", "zeichnenViewClickListener ");

      final Drawing view = new Drawing(context);
      view.postInvalidate();

    }
};
```

this call the Drawing constructor but not the `onDraw( )` method:

```
public class Drawing extends View {

    public Drawing(Context context)  {
        super(context);
        Log.d("Drawing", "Drawing");

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Drawing0", "Drawing0");
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.d("Drawing1", "Drawing1");
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        rect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() / 2);

        Paint blue = new Paint();
        blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        Log.d("Drawing2", "Drawing2");
        canvas.drawRect(rect, blue);
        Log.d("Drawing3", "Drawing3");
    }
}
```

I want to paint lines (now for testing purpose just a rectangle by click) in this view:

View

```
    android:id="@+id/zeichnenView"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    class="com.unitnode.Drawing"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

So how must the class Drawing.class called from main Activity and why `onDraw( )` never gets called?

Comment: Where do you register your touch listener?

Comment: And why do you have `onTouch()` and `drawingOnTouchListener()` with the exact same code?

Comment: All drawing operations should be handled in `onDraw()` with the Canvas object passed into that method.